# How to set an image to state once it's filtered in an array?

Tags: react-native

I have an array:

```
array: [
{
  second: 1,
  source: Thing1,
},
{
  second: 2,
  source: Thing2,
}
]
```

And I want to render the image that is `source` in the array. The source is an imported image.

I want to set the image (`source`) to a state. But I'm not sure what type the state item should be initialised as. I ask this because it's not rendering at all.
Here's the initialised state:

```
filteredPic: null,
```

Here's the function that does the filter:

```
if((time === 1)) {

        filterArrayPic = this.array.filter((item) => {
            return item.second === 1;
        }).map((item) => {
            return console.log(item.source)
        })

         this.setState({

           filteredPic: filterArrayPic 
           }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.filteredPic)
           })          
        }
```

Can you find something wrong with the function or the initialised state type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in the code that you have provided.
1. the filtered array is set to a map and you console log from the map so it wont return anything and this map is not required here at all.
2. As you need a single item you can use the find function instead of filter.

Here is the working version of the code. you can use the block in your component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    filteredPic: null,
  };

  array = [
    {
      second: 1,
      source: require('./assets/snack-icon.png'),
    },
    {
      second: 2,
      source: require('./assets/snack-icon.png'),
    },
  ];

  onPress = () => {
    const filterArrayPic = this.array.find((item) => {
      return item.second === 1;
    });

    console.log(filterArrayPic);
    this.setState(
      {
        filteredPic: filterArrayPic.source,
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.filteredPic);
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ width: 300 }}>
        <Button onPress={this.onPress} title="Set Image" on />
        <Image
          source={this.state.filteredPic}
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```